# Authentication with Windows LIve ID issues

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to sutup the Authentication with Windows LIve ID  and followed this [blog post](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Visual-guide-to-Windows-Live-ID-authentication-with-SharePoint-2010-part-1.aspx) ,everything is working but I have a problem logging in to live INT web site. Whenever I try to log in (https://login.live-int.com/login.srf) , after entering valid email/password I get redirected to the logout page. I tried 2 different accounts (one with existing email address, and other one with newly created @hotmail-int.com address) and 3 different browsers so I'm sure that neither account nor the browser are the cause of this. I also tried to enter wrong password, and in that case I get the message that the password is wrong.

If anyone has any hint about how to log in there It would be very, very helpful. I'm integrating SharePoint 2010 with Windows Live ID and instead of solving some real problems I'm stuck with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out myself and I have blogged it [here](http://ybbest.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/how-to-fix-the-%E2%80%9Clive-int-automatically-logs-out%E2%80%9D/)